# Gradients in Tensorflow are nan after some iterations using Gradient Tape

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I made this small NN using Gradient Tape with custom loss function (Balanced Logarithmic Loss, which just log_loss weighted), but after some iterations I start to get "nan" in the Gradients. This is the code:

```
flag = False
W1, b1 = initialize_parameters_deep(n, layers_dims[0])
W2, b2 = initialize_parameters_deep(layers_dims[0], layers_dims[1])
W3, b3 = initialize_parameters_deep(layers_dims[1], layers_dims[2])

for i in range(5000):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    Z1 = linear_activation_forward(X, W1, b1, 'leaky_relu')
    Z2 = linear_activation_forward(Z1, W2, b2, 'leaky_relu')

    y_before = linear_activation_forward(Z2, W3, b3, 'sigmoid')

    if tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.math.is_nan(y_before), dtype=tf.int32)) > 0:
      break

    y_predict = linear_activation_forward(Z2, W3, b3, 'sigmoid')

    loss = bal_log_loss(y_true=y_true, y_pred =y_predict)

  if ((i+1) % 300) == 0:
      print(f'Iteration: {i}')
      print(f'Loss: {loss}')
      print('_-'*30)


  [dW1, dW2, dW3, db1, db2, db3] = tape.gradient(loss, [W1, W2, W3, b1, b2, b3])

  gradients = [dW1, dW2, dW3, db1, db2, db3]

  for g in gradients:
    if tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.math.is_nan(g), dtype=tf.int32)) > 0:
      print(f'Iteration: {i}')
      print(f'loss: {loss}')
      flag = True
      break
  

  if flag:
    break
  W1.assign_sub(dW1 * learning_rate)
  W2.assign_sub(dW2 * learning_rate)
  W3.assign_sub(dW3 * learning_rate)

  b1.assign_sub(db1 * learning_rate)
  b2.assign_sub(db2 * learning_rate)
  b3.assign_sub(db3 * learning_rate)
```

I read that this problem arises because of the extreme values when using the log function (-inf), but I do not completly understand why and maybe how to fix that, I just placed some break points in the training iterations in order to catch up the nan values and exit the loop, but I really want to understand completly why this happens.

This is  my custom loss funtion:

```
def bal_log_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  epsilon = 1e-10
  m = y_true.shape[-1]

  y_pred = tf.where(y_pred>(1-epsilon), 1-epsilon, y_pred)
  y_pred = tf.where(y_pred<epsilon, epsilon, y_pred)

  n1 = tf.reduce_sum(y_true)
  n0 = tf.reduce_sum(1-y_true)

  w1 = -1/n1
  w0 = -1/n0

  log = tf.where(y_true==1, w1 * tf.math.log(y_pred), w0 * tf.math.log(1-y_pred))
  loss = (tf.reduce_sum(log) / 2) 
  return loss
```

Thanks in advance for any tip or explanation